# Printing from Firefox to network printer does not work

Tags: firefox, printing

I just noticed that since using Ubuntu 12.04(.01) or since some update (can't tell it for sure) I cannot print from Firefox to my network printer (Samsung CLX-3175FN) any more. For a very short moment I can see the Printer icon in the panel on top and then it's gone and nothing happens.

Printing from other applications like Evince or Adobe Acrobat works (so this is not a duplicate of:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/175199/cant-print-from-adobe-reader-or-from-firefox )

I have found a forum entry from somebody having the same issue:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12486689#post12486689
However, other than the poster there, I have a clean install and not an Update of my Ubuntu (I am using 12.04.01 with latest updates).

Even from Chromium printing is working so it is not a Browser-issue in general.
What I noticed is that status message of the printer (but only when printing from Firefox and Chromium) in the print dialog says "Printer 'Samsung-CLX-3175FN' has no toner left". Printer dialog called from Text editor or Evince says "Ready to print.". And although print dialog calling from Chromium gives the same wrong message (there is 13 % toner left says the web interface of the printer) Chromium prints it out fine.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem printing from Firefox to a HP3055 network printer. Doing this seemed to resolve it:

- Within Firefox enter Page Setup (**File > Page Setup**)
- Change the "**Format For**" option from *"Any Printer"* to "*Your Printer*" and try again.

I'm not sure how to make this permanent though..

Hope this helps.